# Dúvida com SSL/TSL e Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis, ssl

Eu fiz uma aplicação para teste e no projeto eu mudei o campo SSL Enabled para True. A aplicação passou a ter duas URL's, sendo uma para o HTTPS e a outra para o HTTP.
Ex:

```
https://localhost:44338/
http://localhost:22786/
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo acessar das duas formas, minha dúvida seria, se eu subir este projeto em um servidor eu preciso fazer alguma configuração especifica ou um redirecionamento ou compra algum certificado? Se tiver que compra um certificado onde eu vou adicionar isso?